# The Day I Realized the Truth (title of the essay)

Tags: tense

That was easy. I picked "The Family Hero."

> Some psychologists also refer to this child as "The Golden Child". This child can do no wrong, **is** praised by the family and commended no matter what the child does.

This is one of the sentences that I took from the essay.  I want to ask why "is" cannot use as a past tense (like "was" praised by the family) as the verbs used in the title are past tense.

Comment: The only thing I find unusual about the sentence is that ***is*** should be repeated before *commended*. This construction is *not* parallel, because of the mixed use of *can* and *is*, so the verb in front of *commended* cannot be simply omitted. (Incidentally, if *was* were used instead, the same would still apply to *commended*.)

Comment: What is the relevance of the title "The day I realized the truth" and the first line "That was easy..." to the question about tense?

Answer (score 0):

*Is* is an auxiliary verb used to denote something that is still happening or true at the time of speaking (present continuous tense). Was is just a simple past tense version of the word.

The sentence you have highlighted appears to be written in the present tense. It may be that the essay reflecting on the past, but the situation still holds to this day.

I.e.

> The child was the star child and still is.